# How to avoid spend long time in onDraw?

Tags: android, bitmap, android-canvas, android-view, ondraw

I am writing an app to draw some data (map of subway data), and the map can be moved/scaled when user touch the screen.
Now I am using View to draw the map, the map is being drawed in Canvas when `onDraw(Canvas canvas)` called.

I caculate the translate x/y and scale when `onTouchEvent` called and then call `invalidate()` to refresh the map.
The `onDraw` method looks like this:

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.save();
    canvas.translate(nowPosX, nowPosY);
    canvas.scale(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor);
    canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);

    for (Subways.Line line : subwayData.getLineList()) {
        for (Subways.Line.Stations:line.getStationList) {
            canvas.drawLine();
            canvas.drawText();
            canvas.drawCircle();
        }
    }

    canvas.restore();
    super.onDraw(canvas);
}
```

But I have a problem now. Every time I move/scale the map, I need to redraw everything and the data is so many and spend lot of time. It will slow when I move/scale the map.

I tried to draw in Bitmap first and move/scale the bitmap everytime `onDraw` called. But if bitmap is small, it will looks fuzzy when I scale. If bitmap is big, it may cause `OutOfMemoryError`.

Is there any way to solve my problem?

Comment: Use one of Canvas.quickReject() method to answer the big question "to draw or not to draw"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On some older Android versions you can improve performance by drawing all the bitmaps at once and all the text at once. Other possibility is to create a Path for each text you have, cache them and use the cache for drawing the Paths everytime a redraw is needed.

Answer (score 1):

You can prepare the map with lines, circles and text drawn on it into many Bitmaps before showing the map to the screen.

Then modify the onDraw() method to make it only draw certain breakdown bitmaps in correct scale.